# How to check ec2 linux instance login history or time stamp

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

We are two user accessing same linux ec2 instance.
How can we see entire login history with time stamp? including the command executed by each user if possible

We both access it remotely from different IPs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **entire login history with timestamp**

**1)** Use [last](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last) command which searches through the [/var/log/wtmp](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp) file by default and show a list of last logged in users. This file records all logins and logouts.

```
last
last -f /var/log/other_wtmp_file
```

Output example:

```
ec2-user pts/0        212.141.41.42    Mon Sep 23 09:21   still logged in
ec2-user pts/1        212.141.41.42    Mon Sep 23 08:33 - 01:46  (17:12)
```

- **including command executed by each user**

**1)** This is usually not enabled by default. You can rely on standard shell history capability which is not so bullet proof but may be sufficient. Use `history` command and `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable in case of `bash` shell to print the time stamp with each history entry. You may try to put this line to the system bash profile (e.g. `/etc/profile` file or create a new one in `/etc/profile.d` directory on RHEL systems):

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d.%m.%y %T"
export HISTTIMEFORMAT
```

**2)** Or you can leverage Linux Auditing System and PAM module [pam_tty_audit](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_tty_audit) for auditing users. Simply put this line to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` on RHEL systems (or similar configuration file on other distros):

```
session   required pam_tty_audit.so disable=* enable=root
```

Then, you can query audit daemon logs with [ausearch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch) tool for tty events:

```
ausearch -ts today -m tty -i
ausearch -ts yesterday -m tty -i
ausearch -ts recent -m tty -i
```

Output (after session logout):

```
type=TTY msg=audit(09/24/2013 02:29:56.394:31312) : tty pid=7032 uid=ec2-user 
auid=ec2-user ses=1239 major=136 minor=0 comm=bash data="ls",<ret>,"last",<ret>,<^D>
```

**3)** Finally, there is still an option to enable process accounting. Install `psacct` package on RHEL systems, enable the service `psacct` and use the [lastcomm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lastcomm) tool to print out information about previously executed commands.

`lastcomm`

Output:

```
man                     root     pts/1      0.00 secs Tue Sep 24 02:19
sh                      root     pts/1      0.00 secs Tue Sep 24 02:19
sh                 F    root     pts/1      0.00 secs Tue Sep 24 02:19
less                    root     pts/1      0.00 secs Tue Sep 24 02:19
```

Answer (score 0):

for the currently log-in on the system you can use the command "w", for some other linux flavors like Ubuntu you can check the /var/log/auth.log and for Centos or Fedora you can check /var/log/secure, you can view user logins and authorization information under auth.log

you should check the last executed command for the user(individually) by checking e.g. .bash_history

Answer (score 0):

You can log the commands executed to a file by changing Bash configuration, and then sync the file to Cloudwatch Logs. Here's a blog post detailing how to do this: http://www.technowise.in/2016/12/log-ec2-bashlinux-commands-to.html